# Looking for graph database for using with c++

Tags: open-source, library, c++

I'm looking for a graph database. I checked couple of them, but there is a problem with c++ driver. A lot of graph database is exists but usually has python or java driver (and also http rest). But I need a really graph database that works with c++. I've checked ArangoDB, Neo4j, OrientDB, AgnesGraph and few more.

I need a database for large scale of data with good performance, for example neo4j has c++ driver but is written with java and is slower that arangodb and orientdb.

To short a long story, I'm looking for a graph database that:

1. Designed for large scale data
2. Has good performance (prefer is that written by c/c++ and not java!)
3. Is good if support index
4. Is open source
5. And most importantly has a c++ driver (good if works with socket and not http rest)
   Please share with me of you have any experience with graph databases with c++

I'm sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 1):

ArangoDB could be used with the C++ driver [fuerte](https://github.com/arangodb/fuerte) that connects with an ArangoDB database over the http and velocystream (optionally ssl encrypted) protocols.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I've seen it, Useful and good database but fuerte wasn't build on windows. And no binary avaible for windows. The velocypack prertequire has compile break with msvc. Did you build it for windows?

Comment: Hi, Fuerte is built on windows alongside the regular arangodb source code, arangosh contains fuerte since 3.4; You need openssl,MSVC,(native windows) CMake and a native windows python installation in order to make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

[Nebula Graph](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula) is an open source graph database written in C++. It also supports [index](https://nebula-graph.io/posts/how-indexing-works-in-nebula-graph/). Take a look and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Can you add the main features of the suggested program and how them fulfill the OP's request?